# Soldered composite video connection not working on Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: composite-video

have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I'm trying to output video from the pads on the back of the PCB, how ever it is not outputting video. I've tested the video with a raspberry pi zero and the video outputted fine. Its just not working with my Pi 3 Model B. When typing:

```
tvservice -s
```

It outputs:

```
state 0x40001 [NTSC 4:3], 720x480 @ 60.00Hz, interlaced
```

The config.txt does not have:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

So it is commented out and not being read, another attempt trying to get it to work I added:

```
hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1
```

to the config.txt also. I need to have the video SOLDERED to the Raspberry Pi! Please help, I've tried everything and nothing is working.

EDIT: The composite display is connected to PP24 on the back of the Pi with the ground connected to PP06. And nothing is connected to the HDMI port.

Comment: Just out of interest why does it need to be soldered?  The 3.5mm jack connection already outputs composite video and audio.

Comment: As Steve has pointed out, this appears to be the same question as your previous one. Please don't repost your question if it doesn't get an answer, as this will not help you to get a quicker answer. Instead, you can earn some rep and place a bounty if you need more attention for your question; see the [help].

Comment: Okay sorry about that, next time I will. It needs to be soldered because it's a project similar to Adafruits PiGRL, so it needs to be in a tight space.